# MeterRegistry HealthIndicator how to use Gauge gauge to report data when observed

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer, gauge, statsd

I am using statsd mertics, right now I am trying to add metric healthIndicator

```
public class xxxHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {
 private final xxx xxx;

    private final MeterRegistry meterRegistry;
    @Autowired
    public xxxHealthIndicator(xxx xxx, @Nullable MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        this.xxx = xxx;
        this.meterRegistry = meterRegistry;
    }

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        return A.getHealth(xxx.getHealth());
    }
}
```

what I am thinking is add code in health():

```
 @Override
    public Health health() {
        if(meterRegistry!=null){
         Gauge gauge = Gauge
// I am confusing about report data when observed, does is means I need to add status change ? 
                .builder("xxxhealth", ????, ????) 

                .tags("status",xxx.getHealth.get("status"))
                .register(meterRegistry);
         }
        return A.getHealth(xxx.getHealth());
    }
```

and the https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.6/reference/html/howto.html#howto.actuator.map-health-indicators-to-metrics, the HealthEndpoint I do not need to add it.

```
 Gauge gauge = Gauge 
                .builder("xxxhealth", ????, this::getStatusCode ) 
                .tags("status",xxx.getHealth().get("status"))
                .register(meterRegistry);
         }
//getHealth() is return a Map
private int getStatusCode(xxx health) {
       String status = health.getHealth().get("status");
        if (Status.UP.equals(status)) {
            return 3;
        }
        if (Status.OUT_OF_SERVICE.equals(status)) {
            return 2;
        }
        if (Status.DOWN.equals(status)) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to register a `Gauge` every time health is called?
You just need to register it once and tell it how to get the value, please check the docs to have better understanding about the `Gauge` concept: https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_gauges

With this, if you put your original code together what is in the Boot docs:

```java
public class xxxHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {
    private final xxx xxx;

    public xxxHealthIndicator(xxx xxx, @Nullable MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        this.xxx = xxx;
        Gauge.builder("xxxHealth", this::getStatusCode).register(registry);
    }

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        return A.getHealth(xxx.getHealth());
    }

    private int getStatusCode() {
        Status status = this.health().getStatus();
        if (Status.UP.equals(status)) {
            return 3;
        }
        if (Status.OUT_OF_SERVICE.equals(status)) {
            return 2;
        }
        if (Status.DOWN.equals(status)) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```